# Extract value from 1x3 numpy array given other two values

Tags: numpy

I have a 1x3 numpy vector of integers. Given a pair of integers, how can I extract the third integer. Each integer in the numpy vector is unique, and the pair will not include itself (e.g. 3 and 3).

for example:

```
>>> nodes
array([3, 5, 7], dtype=int16)
>>> n1 = 3
>>> n2 = 7
```

Given n1, n2, and the 1x3 array, I want the middle value, 5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `np.in1d` to filter out `n1` and `n2` from `nodes`:

```
nodes[~np.in1d(nodes, [n1, n2])]
# array([5])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> arr = np.array([3, 5, 7])
>>> n1 = 3
>>> n2 = 7
>>> arr[(arr != n1) & (arr != n2)][0]
5
```

This works through boolean masking. First exclude values that match the two known values. Since you know there will only be one value left, just take the first element.